# UK business visitor visa / separated status

Tags: visas, uk, applications

I have an exam in the UK and would like to apply for UK business visitor visa.
I am separated from my husband, the legal proceedings are going on. Do I have to mention my partner's details on the visa application? will it affect my visa application? The UK visa page mentioned giving partner's passport number etc. I do not have those details. What papers should I provide?

Comment: Just answer TRUTHFULLY and provide what you have. You may attach a small note explaining your circumstance if you feel it's necessary

Comment: You have to add your husband applicant's ID in your application form.

Comment: @Alex.TT since the couple is separating, the husband is presumably not also traveling, and presumably therefore does not have an applicant ID.

Answer (score 5):

You want to apply for a Standard Visitor Visa and you are separated and in the process of divorce.

> Do I have to mention my partner's details on the visa application?

Let's look at the form...

[image]

The drop down contains the available choices and there is a choice for 'Separated'.  So yes, you should select the option that describes your personal circumstances most closely. If you are in the process of getting a divorce (and have the paperwork to prove it), then the answer is "Separated". The form will then know that the spouse's details are irrelevant and skip over that part of the form.

> will it affect my visa application?

In itself no. It's common. Countless numbers of people get separated and divorced, the number includes consular staff and even government ministers. There is no reason for someone's marital status (of whatever nature) taken alone to affect an application.

> Do I have to mention my partner's details on the visa application?

Not if you are separated. But if you are married and in a trial separation where there is no paperwork (or have not yet filed), then yes. Let's look at the form...

[image]

This makes it pretty clear that the spouse's details are required. But if you are separated without paperwork yet you can click "NO" to "Do they currently live with you". And in that case you get this puppy...

[image]

If you click "YES" to are they travelling with you, you get this expander...

[image]

They do not ask for the spouse's passport number if the spouse is not travelling with you. After that the form will go on to other things, like your parents' details.

> I do not have those details.

That's fine. You can attach a note explaining why you do not have your spouse's details (or any other information they want to see).  The downside is that your application will be moved into the 'orange light' category where applications are not 'straight-forward'. As 'best practices' the applicant should make every attempt to provide the information asked for.

You may not have their contact details, but as you have filed for divorce, the simplest remedy is to inspect your divorce proceedings and locate your spouse's contact details and transfer the information to the form.

---

NOTE: we can't take up the question of whether or not these questions violate privacy or are grounded in law or have a purpose beyond what is stated in the guidance.